# jquery grabbing different id in document.ready

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing a small script that will query a database for a title and whilst you enter your title it brings back suggestions.

I have found an example and managed to create one as below:

```
<head>
<title>Match Form/title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    {

        $("#course").autocomplete("get_title_list.php", {

            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            selectFirst: false
        });
        $("#course").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            $("#course_val").val(data[1]);
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
```

That then works and allows to print out my result on the page, my next task is to have multiple text boxs along multiple titles and allow someone to search the database and then return the results to the allocated box.

I know id need to assign each box an ID and then select that id in the jquery which is where i am struggling.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$('#ID1,#ID2,#ID3)`.  Actually, I'd suggest a class instead of IDs: `$('.autocomplete')`.

Comment: thanks Hazmat is there any chance you could elaborate on that please? im fairly new to jquery thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an ID, change the text boxes to classes. Something like this should work with the boxes having the class "course":

```
     $(".course").autocomplete("get_title_list.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
    $(".course").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        $(this).next(".course_val").val(data[1]);
    });
```

Comment: I now have a now problem, I need to be able to copy and paste the data into a spreadsheet and it doesnt work so well with textboxes i have tried outputting the results to a label and this doesnt work do you have any ideas ?

Comment: To do this you could change all of your `course_val` text boxes to labels, then instead of `$(this).next(".course_val").val(data[1]);` use `$(this).next(".course_val").text(data[1]);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a class instead of an ID.  IDs need to be unique, but you can have multiple elements with the same class, so you can select them all at once easily.

Example:

```
<input id="A" class="auto" />
<input id="B" class="auto" />

<script>
    $('.auto').autocomplete({}); // the  '.' is used to select by class
</script>
```